# acceder a un td de la tabla al hacer click

Tags: javascript, jquery

buenas quisiera saber como puedo acceder a una parte de mi tabla, la parte donde pongo el label-success le asigno un id al td para hacer algo pero no me funciona igual le puse id al span y lo mismo. no se que hago mal

use esta funcion no me funciono

```
$( '#idse' ).dblclick(function() {
  alert( "s" );
});
$( '#idven' ).dblclick(function() {
  alert( "v" );
});
$( '#idge' ).dblclick(function() {
  alert( "g" );
});
```

codigo

```
for(var i=0; i<resp.length; i++)
{
 var diffTime = moment(fecha).diff(resp[i].fecha_registro);
        var dias = diffTime/86400000;
        console.log(dias);
     var labelType = (resp[i].res == 'aprob') ? 'label-success' : 'label-warning';
     var labelType1 = (resp[i].se == 'aprob') ? 'label-success' : 'label-warning';
     var labelType2 = (resp[i].ven == 'aprob') ? 'label-success' : 'label-warning';
     var labelType3 = (resp[i].ge == 'aprob') ? 'label-success' : 'label-warning';
     var boton = (resp[i].as== '') ? '<div data-id="'+resp[i].id+'" data-nombre= "'+resp[i].nom+'" class="btn btn-primary registrar_o">Asignar</div>' : resp[i].as;

     html+= '<tr><td data-id="'+resp[i].id+'">'+resp[i].fecha_registro+
        '</td><td class="center" data-id="'+resp[i].id+'"><span class="label ' + labelType + '">'+resp[i].res+
        '</span></td><td id="idse" class="center" data-id="'+resp[i].id+'"><span class= "label ' + labelType1 +'">'+resp[i].se+
        '</span></td><td id="idven" class="center" data-id="'+resp[i].id+'"><span class="label ' + labelType2 +'">'+resp[i].ven+
        '</span></td><td id="idge" class="center" data-id="'+resp[i].id+'"><span class="label ' + labelType3 +'">'+resp[i].ge+
        '</span></td></tr>';
}

$('#body').html(html);
```

Comment: muchas cosas mal amigo, en primera metes un ciclo for, y el ID se repite para todas las filas que pongas, cuando deberian ser unicos, la otra es que el metodo double click no se ejecuta por que estas generando contenido dinamico, y bueno.

Comment: Si, pero lo pongo en cada uno por que cada uno va a hacer cosas diferentes al hacer click y para traerme los datos

Comment: Ya lo solucione en vez de id los puse como clases para cada columna y asi pude acceder a ellos

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que todo el código está en la mísma Hoja de JavaScript, es decir, los eventos asignados a los ID's deben asignar-se después de la assignación del HTML dinámico al elemento .

Puedes ayudarte de funciones, es decir...

```
function _addEventDBLClick() {
    if ($('#idven')) {
      $('#idven').on('dblclick',function(){
        alert( "s" );
      }
   }
  /*
$( '#idse' ).dblclick(function() {
  alert( "s" );
});
$( '#idven' ).dblclick(function() {
  alert( "v" );
});
$( '#idge' ).dblclick(function() {
  alert( "g" );
}); 
  */
}
```

Llamandola al finalizar después de la línea:

```
$('#body').html(html);
_addEventDBLClick();
```

Comment: Gracias amigo si me funciono pero solo para el primer registro de mi tabla para los q le siguen no me funciono, checare que hago mal

Comment: Claro compañero, esa asignación del evento clic no puede ser referenciado por ID sí tienes más registros, es decir, en vez de ID = "idven", debería ser una clase, es decir, class = "ven", ya que jQuery recoge por ID un único elemento, pero por clase, recogerá todos y deberás iterar-los elementos que contengan la clase y añadir el evento